# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The input data is not a complete block.'

Tags: c#, encryption

I am new to decryption, and trying to decrypt like ColdFusion was in the previous version. I am getting this error, and not sure what it means.

```cs
string cipherText = "text";
//this is from coldfusion
String key = "key";
//var AES_algorithm = "AES";
//var AES_encoding = "hex";
//<cfset Result = #Decrypt(val, AES_Private_Key, AES_algorithm, AES_encoding)#>

if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");

//not sure what this is?
String iv = "1020304050607080";

if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

byte[] bytearraytodecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

AesCryptoServiceProvider keydecrypt = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
keydecrypt.BlockSize = 128;
keydecrypt.KeySize = 128;
keydecrypt.Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
keydecrypt.IV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
keydecrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
keydecrypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

ICryptoTransform crypto1 = keydecrypt.CreateDecryptor(keydecrypt.Key, keydecrypt.IV);

byte[] returnbytearray = crypto1.TransformFinalBlock(bytearraytodecrypt, 0, bytearraytodecrypt.Length);
crypto1.Dispose();
return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(returnbytearray);
```

Comment: Please review the code formatting in my edit for reference in future posts. Stack Overflow uses the backtick character for code formatting, 3 for blocks and 1 in-paragraph.

Comment: I thought that I did it right. I'll try harder next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means what it says. In CBC mode the plaintext is first padded to a full number of blocks. This always happens for PKCS#7 padding. Then each block of plaintext is encrypted sequentially, using the previously encrypted block as vector; this block is XOR'ed with the plaintext.

The initial vector (IV) needs to be provided, and for CBC mode it needs to be fully unpredictable to an attacker. That generally means that it should consist of randomized bytes. A constant, encoded string doesn't meet this requirement.

Of course, the result consists of ciphertext blocks. Now if the decryption routine encounters a number of bytes that is not a multiple of the block size, you'll get the error. That means that either the message has additional data, or it hasn't been encoded correctly. It may also mean that a different mode than CBC was used, or even CBC with ciphertext stealing.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. The best way to say thanks on SO is to accept the answer - if it doesn't please indicate that to the answerer. Happy to go into details.

Comment: I don't know how to accept the answer. I don't see that anywhere. I'm probably just blind, lol.

Comment: @CharlotteWilliams It's the grey V next to the answer, on the left :) It's of course also present in the [help of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)